# How do I make a crescent?

Tags: modeling

I want to make a perfectly round crescent but no matter how I tweak it ends up looking lumpy when I use a curve extrusion. As I subdivide segments and try to eyeball each point's radius scale... it just looks bad.

I am stumped how does one make a perfectly circular crescent?

[image]

Comment: Try adding a circle and deleting half of it. That might work.

Answer (score -1):

Like this?
[image]

I used a bezier curve, The less points you put the smoother it is.

Comment: It's not even round.